# Why use if and for within a list definition in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart supports using "if" and "for" during creation of a list :

```
var nav = [
  'Home',
  'Furniture',
  'Plants',
  if (promoActive) 'Outlet'
];
```

and:

```
var listOfInts = [1, 2, 3];
var listOfStrings = [
  '#0',
  for (var i in listOfInts) '#$i'
];
assert(listOfStrings[1] == '#1');
```

What is the point of this ? How is it better than creating a list, and appending to it afterwards like in other programming languages:

```
var nav = [
  'Home',
  'Furniture',
  'Plants',
];

if (promoActive) nav.add('Outlet');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the following proposal to understand this better:

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md

> A key goal of Flutter's API design is that, as much as possible, the
> textual layout of the code reflects the nesting structure of the
> resulting user interface.

It seems that the reason is simply for code readability purposes in flutter. For example, the following code:

```
var command = [
  engineDartPath,
  frontendServer,
];
for (var root in fileSystemRoots) {
  command.add('--filesystem-root=$root');
}
for (var entryPointsJson in entryPointsJsonFiles) {
  if (fileExists("$entryPointsJson.json")) {
    command.add(entryPointsJson);
  }
}
command.add(mainPath);
```

can instead be written in a more concise form:

```
var command = [
  engineDartPath,
  frontendServer,
  for (var root in fileSystemRoots) '--filesystem-root=$root',
  for (var entryPointsJson in entryPointsJsonFiles)
    if (fileExists("$entryPointsJson.json")) entryPointsJson,
  mainPath
];
```

There are many more examples in the document, but the short answer seems to be simply for readability and conciseness of code.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple factors playing a role:

- performance
- readability

## Readability

The main reason why this feature was implemented is for `ListView`/`Stack` and all other widgets with a `children` parameter.

These widgets do not support `null` as parameter, which caused a significant amount of frustration (which led to this github issue: [Allow null values in `child` or `children[]` collections to signal that an element should not be drawn](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17862))

In short, the problem is that the declarative nature of widgets means that using `add` & co isn't really an option.

Without `if`/`for` inside collections, we would have to write:

```dart
List<Widget> children = [
  Foo(),
]

if (condition)
  children.add(Bar());

return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: children,
  ),
);
```

which makes it difficult to understand what is rendered on screen since the *build* method is now fragmented

Alternatively, we would have to write:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Foo(),
      condition ? Bar() : null,
    ].where((e) => e != null).toList(),
  ),
);
```

This is more readable but significantly lack in flexibility as anything more complex than this example will be difficult to implement

As a solution, we can now write:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Foo(),
      if (condition)
        Bar(),
    ]
  ),
);
```

This is both readable, easy to write, and not error-prone.

## Performance

An interesting aspect of this feature is, it increases the performance of your Flutter apps.

On thing to consider when writing:

```dart
final list = <Widget>[
  Foo(),
];

if (condition)
  list.add(Bar());
```

is that by using `add`, the list size changes over time. This means that any `add` can potentially cause the `List` to be re-allocated to support more items, which is expensive.

The same issue applies to:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Foo(),
    condition ? Bar() : null,
  ].where((e) => e != null).toList(),
)
```

where we are effectively instantiating the `List` twice and iterating over all of its items twice too (once for the `where`, another time by `ListView`)

These performance issues do not happen when using `if`/`for` inside collections.
When writing:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Foo(),
    if (condition)
      Bar(),
  ],
);
```

this immediately allocates the `List` with the correct size, and the allocation if performed once and only once.

The reason is, in reality this syntax is equivalent to:

```dart
List<Widget> children;
if (condition)
  children = [
    Foo(),
    Bar(),
  ];
else
  children = [
    Foo(),
  ]
```

which involves neither `add` nor `where`/`toList`